# call a function somewhere at a long string

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hey is it possible to call a function somewhere at a long string where I have multiple + values that get added? As example look down please.

```
function test() {
console.log('I am fine!')
}

var temp = 'hello..' + 'how do you feel?' + test() + 'something else'
```

This also didn´t work for me

```
var test2 = function test() {
console.log('I am fine!')
}

var temp = 'hello..' + 'how do you feel?' + test2 + 'something else'
```

I need somewhere in the defintion of var temp to add a call of function test() - Any ideas?

EDIT to the answer of this questions. This was what I´am looking for maybe this helped somebody else

```
function test() {
console.log('lorem1')
console.log('lorem2')
//.. do other stuff
return '\n'
}

var temp = 'lorem' + 'ipsum' + test() + 'something else'
```

Comment: You need to return the value, `console.log` only prints it.

Comment: ah thank you!!!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you can do is append the result of a function onto a string, likewise:

```
function test() {
  return 'I am fine!'
}

var temp = 'hello..' + 'how do you feel?' + test()
```

You just have to ensure that your function is returning the value you want to append.

Comment: Glad to help! If it answers your question, please accept it as the right answer. If it doesn't answer your question, we can try to improve the answer :)

Comment: I understand now that you can return values now in this way. But imagine the function I want to execute has included a lot of different stuff like for loop example. How can I call those functions at a long string? The problem is I can´t execute it after or before I need it in middle of the string because my main project has a real big string where hundreds of new values get added with + 'lorem' + 'ipsum' and I need to call a function anywhere between and not just return values.

Comment: It is ok to have for loops in the function (you can make it as complex as you want), all you have to ensure is that at the end, the function returns a string. If you want to edit your question with a more complex situation, I can update the answer to show how you could go about doing it

Comment: No thank you already helped me. I understand now what you mean. This is awesome never thought it would be so easy! thank you again :)! have a nice day!.